# Entity Framework Migrations: Timeout SqlException during migrating

Tags: entity-framework, sqlexception, entity-framework-migrations, command-timeout

Sql Server is accessible. I want to migrate database using Entity Framework migrations. There i have "Images" table with 130k records having images. In migration there "INDEX" added to these table using "CREATE INDEX". I get `SqlException` that command timeout is expired. But in connection string i can define only Connect Timeout. I tried define Command Timeout here:
`(IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout` but it didn't help me.
And in DbMigrator too, but he hasn't such property anywhere.

So i need help, I should define `CommandTimeout` for migration in Entity Framework, but don't know how to do this.
Help me plz, sorry for bad English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in EF4.  It was added as a feature to the release candidate of EF5 which was released this week: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded EF5 and successfully set CommandTimeout property. Migration finished throw few minutes

Comment: The link is broken.